# Delphi 2010 Class TraCoreModule not found

Tags: delphi, activex

When i run my application it tells me that "`Class TraCoreModule not found`". I tried to google witch class this is or where it comes from but no results.

Can anyone tell me what module this is or why i get this error please?

The application connects to a sql server database and updates a few fields.
It also uses ActiveX to send emails.
I am using Woll2Woll.

I wish i could provide more information but this is all i have.

I tried to locate the error in my code by printing debug messages in a memmo but this does not help.

Comment: When does this happen? Have you examined the callstack at point of error? This could be related to a unregistered class during DFM streaming. But hard to tell, we do have even less info than you.

Comment: I would like to exclude Woll2Woll components and check if such a problem rises again. If so, you definitely should to check out your DFM-file as **nil** suggested or build a new application with all components you use. It is a way I usually use when encounter the same problem.

Comment: I have re-written the whole application but still no luck, I managed to trace it to Report Builder's templates : 
`dmMain.Invoice.Template.DatabaseSettings.Name := dmMain.qReports.fieldbyname('cUserName').AsString;
                      dmMain.Invoice.Template.LoadFromDatabase;`

Any suggestions?

Comment: @JpSilver, you could better make a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and place it in your question so any user will be able to help you. From my minimal experience of work with SQL I cannot see in the code you have provided in your last comment any reasons that may cause described problem. May the force be with you!

Comment: @Dima thank you for your help but as you can see i solved the issue.

Comment: @JpSilver glad to see you were able to solve this puzzle. Never give up!

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the issue. The TppReport was corrupted...